# How to add a Jersey ClientResponseFilter

Tags: jersey, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

When defining a jersey `ContainerResponseFilter`, we added it as follows:

```
PackagesResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.company.xxx");
rc.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new MyContainerResponseFilter());
```

We have also created a `ClientRequestFilter`, which I understand will be called before the endpoint is invoked.

The question is, how (presumably using `PackagesResourceConfig`) is a `ClientResponseFilter` added?

The following will throw a runtime error:

```
rc.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new ClientResponseFilter());
```

and there is no method such as `rc.getClientResponseFilters()`

Thanks

Comment: ClientResponseFilter is for the client, not the server

Comment: `ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig(); config.getSingletons().add(new YourClientResponseFilter()); Client client = Client.create(config)`

Comment: Thanks very much. Within the ClientResponseFilter, how do you send the response back to the original browser which initiated the request, rather than forwarding it in the chain? This would be necessary for an authentication handshake challenge - when the browser does not send an authentication header and the filter has to redirect back to the browser to tell it to add the header.